# Firebase auth resets when I refresh a different Route path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{background:'floralwhite'}}>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/calendar' component={Calendar} />
          <Route path='/config' component={UserConfig} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}
```

I am using `react-router-dom` `Route` to create different paths in my web app. And I use these paths in my `navbar` that renders like this:

```
  render() {
      return(
        <div className="navbar">
          <div className="logo-container">
            <img src={Logo}></img>
          </div>

          <div className="left-link-container">
          </div>

          <div className="right-link-container">
            <span style={{color:'white'}} onClick={this.handleLogout}>Sign Out</span>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/config"><span style={{color:'white', marginRight:'2em'}}>Configuration</span></Link>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/calendar"><span style={{color:'white', marginRight:'2em'}}>Calendar</span></Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

So, clicking the Calender would lead me to the `/calendar` path. There is no problem and everything works as intended. However, when I refresh on the `/calendar` page, it somehow logs off from my firebase authentication.

My authentication happens in my `Home` component as follows:

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
        localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
        localStorage.removeItem('user')
      }
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.user ? (
          <div>
            <Navbar />
          </div>) :
          (<Login />)}
      </div>


    )
  };
```

I do conditionally render the component and lead the user to the Login page when it's not logged on. It auto logs the user off when I refresh from other paths defined in my `App.js`. I need to fix this because I used `fire.auth().currentUser.uid` to get the uid of the user in other components with a different path.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean it logs off? After refresh onAuthStateChanged is called with the `user` object no?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following pages.

I think to use a React HOOKS is better.

#### use a React HOOKS

Firebase + React HOOKS Authentication Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_wZCW6wXIo

#### use a higher-order component

A Firebase in React Tutorial for Beginners [2019]

https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/#firebase-authentication